# It's there a way to import Service or files globally in Anguar 8?

Tags: angular, angular8

I use Swift before, and in Swift you don't need to do any extra thing to use any class and constants anywhere . so It's there a way to do the same thing in angular without use `import {someService} from '...path'`?

Comment: This is not possible in javascript/typescript at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `import {someService} from '...path'` is required to import something in Typescript/ES6. This is not Angular specific.

Think about it, for some reasons you have two `FooService` in `..path1` and `..path2` (duplicate name ), which one will your code use?

So in this case, you explicity tell to use let's say
`import {FooService} in '..path1'` if that's what you really intended.

Hope this helps